# How to configure DATADOG agent .../postgres.d/conf.yaml with multiple custom_queries (SELECT statements)

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, datadog

It works with one SELECT statement but did not with two.

```
   custom_queries:
    - metric_prefix: mars
      query: SELECT substring(query, 1, 50) AS query, round(total_time::numeric, 2) AS total_time, calls, round(mean_time::numeric, 2) AS mean, round((100 * total_time / sum(total_time::numeric) OVER ())::numeric, 2) AS percentage_cpu FROM pg_stat_statements ORDER BY total_time DESC LIMIT 25
      columns:
        - name: query
          type: tag
        - name: total_time
          type: gauge
        - name: calls
          type: gauge
        - name: mean
          type: gauge
        - name: percentage_cpu
          type: gauge
      tags:
        - query:cpu
    - metric_prefix: venus
      query: SELECT count(*) AS csum FROM pg_stat_statement
      columns:
        - name: csum
          type: gauge
      tags:
        - query:sum
```

It passed the checks, datadig-agent status output is clear, but the datadog main menu Metric --> Explore does not show the csum metric.

Comment: Have you considered using an implicit join to get data from both tables in one query?

Comment: Thanks a lot bwest for your reply. Actually I made a stupid typo (second select view name  has a missing "s"  at the end). I am sorry, I could not see the forest ...